# Run queries on Meteor server side using node-inspector

Tags: meteor, npm, node-inspector

I'm looking for a way to **run queries** on a meteor server through the node-inspector debugger.
The debugger and everything is **already setup** i.e I can put breakpoint, pause the execution, watch for the code through Chome etc…

But while trying to run a query requiring to go into the meteor events loop
for example:

> Meteor.users.find().fetch()

I get the error:

> Error: Can't wait without a fiber

I therefore tried to encapsule the query through a fiber but while trying to import the objet:

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
```

It seems that the Npm is itself not defined

```
ReferenceError: Npm is not defined
```

It seems I'm out of context… how can I retrieve the right context scope to achieve this ? (or any other way to solve my issue)

Comment: Are you try to evaluate this in console or watch section, or this is a part of your code?

Comment: @3y3 in the console of the Chrome client connected on the node-inspector debugging service. Note that a workaround is currently to use the "meteor mongo" command.